# HTML form auto fill values?

Tags: html

if I had a HTML form like so...

```
    <form>
    First name: <input type="text" name="firstname" /><br />
    Last name: <input type="text" name="lastname" /> 
    </form>
```

How would I auto fill both First name and Last Name with a default value? e.g "joe".

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the [value attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#adef-value-INPUT).

… but please make them sensible defaults (e.g. "The user's name as stored in their account on your site") and not examples.

(And do use [label elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.9) instead of free text for your labels).

Answer (score 3):

Use the value attribute

```
<form>
First name: <input type="text" name="firstname" value="john" /><br />
Last name: <input type="text" name="lastname" value="doe" /> 
</form>
```